# How to label asymptotes in plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make the plot function to label the x-coordinate of the vertical asymptotes. I also want it red dashed. I tried this but obviously it is not correct:

```
Plot[(x - 2)/((x - 1) (x + 2)), {x, -8, 8}, ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashing[Small], Red}]
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the reference page of [`ExclusionsStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html), the syntax `ExclusionsStyle -> {s, sb}` uses the style `s` for the interiors of excluded subregions, and the style `sb` for the boundaries of excluded subregions.

With the expression `ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashing[Small], Red}`, and as can be seen from the output, you are making the lines dashed and the four points red. If you want the vertical asymptotes red dashed with no particular style on the points, you should use instead the syntax `ExclusionsStyle -> s`, and wrap the different style properties in `Directive`, so that they can be applied to the same graphics primitive.

Doing so, you get the expected result:

```
Plot[(x - 2)/((x - 1) (x + 2)), {x, -8, 8}, 
     ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Dashing[Small], Red]
]
```

[image]

---

*Update following comments.* In versions prior to 11.0, the excluded regions need to be given explicitly as a value of the option `Exclusions` in order to get the proper styling:

```
Plot[(x - 2)/((x - 1) (x + 2)), {x, -8, 8}, 
     Exclusions -> {x == -2, x == 1}, 
     ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Dashing[Small], Red]
]
(* same output as above *)
```

Comment: What's your `$Version`? I can't reproduce it: [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/xxXjh).

Comment: @corey979 in version 10 it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I guess in versions before 11 like this:

```
style = {Red, Dashing[Small]};
line1 = Line[{{-2, -10}, {-2, 10}}];
line2 = Line[{{1, -10}, {1, 10}}];

plot = Plot[(x - 2)/((x - 1) (x + 2)), {x, -8, 8}, 
  Exclusions -> {-2, 1}, PlotRange -> {All, {-3, 3}}, 
  Epilog -> {Directive[style], line1, line2}]
```

[image]